# How to call a .net web service that returns an ArrayList to Android

Tags: .net, android, web-services, arraylist, ksoap

I am trying to retreive an `ArrayList` from a .NET web service using ksoap.

The data does not seem to be able to enter my `coo arraylist`.

How can this be solved? Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope =
    new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    ArrayList <String> coo = new ArrayList <String>();

    try{
        androidHttpTransport.call(bustop_SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        java.util.Vector<Object> receivedStrings = (java.util.Vector<Object>)envelope.getResponse();
        if(receivedStrings !=null)
        {
            for(Object curStrings : receivedStrings)
            {
                coo.add(curStrings.toString());
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
```

This is the raw output of the web service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <ArrayOfAnyType xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"; xmlns="FYPJWebService.com">;
      <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">1.278217,103.837517</anyType>
      <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">1.278300,103.837705</anyType>
      <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">1.281510,103.840888</anyType>
      <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">1.285616,103.844446</anyType>
   </ArrayOfAnyType>
```

Comment: Can you post the RAW output of the web service?

Comment: This is the raw output of the web service

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <ArrayOfAnyType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://FYPJWebService.com">
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">1.278217,103.837517</anyType> 
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">1.278300,103.837705</anyType> 
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">1.281510,103.840888</anyType> 
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">1.285616,103.844446</anyType> 
     
    </ArrayOfAnyType>

Comment: Can you paste the value received in `receivedStrings` please?

Answer (score 0):

[KSoap2](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/). That should help.

Comment: Yes i am using KSOAP2 to call the webservice. I am currently trying to call a list of array from the web services. I am trying to store the arraylist's data into the variable coo, but the data cant seem to be stored. Are there any guides on ksoap2 avalible that can assit me?

Comment: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data

Comment: Thanks for the guide, are there any guides on caaling arrays or arraylist webservice too?

Comment: I'm literally just posting results from google searches. Look around on the internet, implement the code I suggested above and if you run into difficulties, post your code with questions and somebody will help.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest you is to convert that ArrayList to a String array. You could refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884829/web-service-code-not-returning-array-of-string)

You could also convert your [ArrayList to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082688/convert-arraylist-to-string-array-in-android) in Android

Then in the web service code on the server side add some delimiter like "#" that would separate each individual item of your ArrayList and store in a String Array.

On the Android side then you could call the web service like this:

```
 public String[] call()
 {
    SoapPrimitive responsesData = null; 

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope( 
    SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
    envelope.dotNet = true; 
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    androidHttpTransport.debug = true; 

    try {

    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    responsesData = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse(); 
    System.out.println(" --- response ---- " + responsesData); 

    } catch (SocketException ex) { 
    ex.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 

    System.out.println( " ----" + responsesData );

    String serviceResponse= responsesData .toString(); 


    String[] temp; 
    String delimiter = "#"; 
    temp= serviceResponse.split(delimiter);
    System.out.println( " ---- length ---- " + temp.length); 

    return temp; 

 }
```

Hope that helps